# Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/policytool" (-1)

Tags: java, java-security, adoptopenjdk

How to resolve the following problem?

```
$ policytool 
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/policytool" (-1)
$
```

**OS:** Mac

---

**Update:**

It works for JDK1.8.0_181 but not for JDK15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`policytool` was deprecated in JDK 9 and was removed in JDK 10: [JDK 10 Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/10-relnote-issues.html). So, if you look in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`, the file should not be there, which explains the error.

You can use any text editor to edit policy files: [Policy File Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)